# How do I create multiplayer with a 3D LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have been working on creating an MMO 3D game (I am not sure on the name or the goal of the game yet... still in indev). I have tried using java sockets and even tried KryoNet, yet I still haven't been able to figure out how to integrate multiplayer into the game!

Here is the code to my main class, my preloading class, and my player class.(They don't have the class declaration, the package declaration, or the imports, by the way)

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DisplayManager.createDisplay();
    PreLoading preLoading = new PreLoading();
    Loader loader = preLoading.loader;
    Camera camera = preLoading.camera;
    Player player = preLoading.player;
    MasterRenderer renderer = preLoading.renderer;
    Terrain terrain = preLoading.terrain;
    GuiRenderer guiRenderer = preLoading.guiRenderer;
    while (!PreLoading.finished) {
        if (PreLoading.finished) {
            break;
        }
    }
    DEBUG(1, "Starting Game!");
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        player.move(terrain);
        camera.move();
        renderer.processEntity(player);
        renderer.processTerrain(terrain);
        for (Entity entity : preLoading.entities) {
            renderer.processEntity(entity);
        }
        renderer.render(preLoading.lights, camera);
        DisplayManager.updateFPS();
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();

    }
    DEBUG(1, "Stoping Game!");
    guiRenderer.cleanUp();
    renderer.cleanUp();
    loader.cleanUP();
    DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    DEBUG(1, "Game stopped!");
}

public static void DEBUG(int level, String msg) {
    Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String formatted = sdf.format(d);
    switch (level) {
    case (1):
        System.out.println("[" + formatted + "] [Information] " + msg);
        break;
    case (2):
        System.out.println("[" + formatted + "] [Warning] " + msg);
        break;
    case (3):
        System.out.println("[" + formatted + "] [Error] " + msg);
        break;
    }
}
```

PreLoading Class:

```
public static Loader loader = new Loader();
public static TerrainTexture backgroundTexture = new TerrainTexture(loader.loadTexture("grassy"));
public static TerrainTexture rTexture = new TerrainTexture(loader.loadTexture("mud"));
public static TerrainTexture gTexture = new TerrainTexture(loader.loadTexture("pinkflowers"));
public static TerrainTexture bTexture = new TerrainTexture(loader.loadTexture("mossPath256"));

public static TerrainTexturePack texturePack = new TerrainTexturePack(backgroundTexture, rTexture, gTexture, bTexture);
public static TerrainTexture blendMap = new TerrainTexture(loader.loadTexture("blendMap"));
public static TexturedModel pine = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("pine", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("pine")));
public static TexturedModel tree = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("lowPolyTree", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("lowPolyTree")));
public static TexturedModel grass = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("grassModel", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("grassTexture")));

public static ModelTexture fernTextureAtlas = new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("fern"));

public static TexturedModel fern = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("fern", loader), fernTextureAtlas);

public static TexturedModel lamp = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("lamp", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("lamp")));

public static Terrain terrain = new Terrain(0, -1, loader, texturePack, blendMap, "heightMap");

public static List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

public static MasterRenderer renderer = new MasterRenderer(loader);

public static TexturedModel playerModel = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("person", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("playerTexture")));
public Player player = new Player(playerModel, new Vector3f(100, 5, -150), 0, 180, 0, 0.6f);
public static boolean finished = false; 
public Camera camera = new Camera(player);
//List<GuiTexture> guis = new ArrayList<GuiTexture>();
public static GuiRenderer guiRenderer = new GuiRenderer(loader);
public static List<Light> lights = new ArrayList<Light>();
public PreLoading() throws Exception {
    fernTextureAtlas.setNumberOfRows(2);
    Random random = new Random(676452);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            float x = random.nextFloat() * 800 - 400;
            float z = random.nextFloat() * -600;
            float y = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(x, z);

            entities.add(new Entity(fern, random.nextInt(4), new Vector3f(x, y, z), 0, random.nextFloat(), 0, 0.9f));

        }
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            float x = random.nextFloat() * 800 - 400;
            float z = random.nextFloat() * -600;
            float y = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(x, z);

            entities.add(new Entity(pine, new Vector3f(x, y, z), 0, random.nextFloat(), 0, 3));
            x = random.nextFloat() * 800 - 400;
            z = random.nextFloat() * -600;
            y = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(x, z);

            entities.add(new Entity(tree, new Vector3f(x, y, z), 0, random.nextFloat() * 360, 0, random.nextFloat() * 0.1f + 0.6f));
        }
        float x = random.nextFloat() * 800 - 400;
        float z = random.nextFloat() * -600;
        float y = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(x, z);

        entities.add(new Entity(grass, new Vector3f(x, y, x), 0, random.nextFloat() * 360, 0, 1));
        grass.getTexture().setHasTransparency(true);
        grass.getTexture().setUseFakeLighting(true);
        grass.getTexture().setHasTransparency(true);
    }



    lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(0, 10000, -7000), new Vector3f(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f)));
    lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(185, 10, -293), new Vector3f(2, 0, 0), new Vector3f(1, 0.01f, 0.002f)));
    lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(370, 17, -300), new Vector3f(0, 2, 2), new Vector3f(1, 0.01f, 0.002f)));
    lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(293, 7, -305), new Vector3f(2, 2, 0), new Vector3f(1, 0.01f, 0.002f)));

    entities.add(new Entity(lamp, new Vector3f(185, terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(185, -293), -293), 0, 0, 0, 1));
    entities.add(new Entity(lamp, new Vector3f(370, terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(370, -300), -300), 0, 0, 0, 1));
    entities.add(new Entity(lamp, new Vector3f(293, terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(293, -305), -305), 0, 0, 0, 1));

    MasterRenderer renderer = new MasterRenderer(loader);

    TexturedModel playerModel = new TexturedModel(ObJLoader.loadObjModel("person", loader), new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("playerTexture")));
    Player player = new Player(playerModel, new Vector3f(100, 5, -150), 0, 180, 0, 0.6f);

    Camera camera = new Camera(player);
    //List<GuiTexture> guis = new ArrayList<GuiTexture>();
    GuiRenderer guiRenderer = new GuiRenderer(loader);
    finished = true;
}
```

Player Class:

```
private String customName;
private boolean customNameVisible;
private String displayName;
private String username;
private String address;
private boolean allowFlight;
private int energy;
private int health;
private int hunger;
private int thirst;
private boolean isFalling = false;
private boolean isFlying;
private float experience;
private int maxHealth;
private String playerListName;
private float walkSpeed;
private float runSpeed;
private float turnSpeed;
private float jumpPower;
private float straifSpeed;
private float gravityPower;
private int gameMode;
private String UUID;
private String password;
private String IPAddress;

private float currentSpeed = 0;
private float currentStraifSpeed = 0;
private float currentTurnSpeed = 0;
private float upwardsSpeed = 0;
public float angleChange;
public boolean thirdPerson = false;
private float X;
private float Y;
private float Z;
public Player(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, float scale)  throws Exception {
    super(model, position, rotX, rotY, rotZ, scale);
    this.walkSpeed = Constants.Player_Walk_Speed;
    this.runSpeed = Constants.Player_Run_Speed;
    this.turnSpeed = Constants.Player_Turn_Speed;
    this.jumpPower = Constants.Player_Jump_Power;
    this.straifSpeed = Constants.Player_Straif_Speed;
    this.gravityPower = Constants.Player_Gravity_Power;
    this.health = (int) Constants.Player_Default_Health;
    this.maxHealth = (int) Constants.Player_Default_Health;
    this.hunger = (int) Constants.Player_Default_Hunger;
    this.energy = (int) Constants.Player_Default_Energy;
    this.X = position.x;
    this.Y = position.y;
    this.Z = position.z;
}

public void move(Terrain terrain) throws Exception {
    checkInputs();
    this.increaseRotation(0, currentTurnSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(), 0);
    currentTurnSpeed = 0;
    float distance = currentSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    float dx = (float) (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.getRotY())));
    float dz = (float) (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.getRotY())));
    float distance1 = currentStraifSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    float dx1 = (float) (distance1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.getRotY() + 90)));
    float dz1 = (float) (distance1 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.getRotY() + 90)));
    this.increasePosition(dx, 0, dz);
    this.increasePosition(dx1, 0, dz1);
    upwardsSpeed += gravityPower * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    this.increasePosition(0, upwardsSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(), 0);
    float terrainHeight = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(this.getPosition().x, this.getPosition().z);
    if (this.getPosition().y < terrainHeight) {
        upwardsSpeed = 0;
        isFalling = false;
        this.getPosition().y = terrainHeight;
    }
    if (!thirdPerson) {
        angleChange = Mouse.getDX() * 0.3f;
        this.increaseRotation(0, -angleChange, 0);
    }
    this.X = this.getPosition().x;
    this.Y = this.getPosition().y;
    this.Z = this.getPosition().z;
}

public void gainHealthAndEnergy(){
    long befTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > befTime + 600){
            if(!(energy <= 0)){
                energy += energy / 2;
            } else {
                energy += 20;
            }
            break;
        }
        while(true){
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > befTime + 2000){
                if (hunger > 950)
                    health += 5;
                if (hunger < 50)
                    health -= 5;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getCustomName() {
    return customName;
}

public void setCustomName(String customName) {
    this.customName = customName;
}

public boolean isCustomNameVisible() {
    return customNameVisible;
}

public void setCustomNameVisible(boolean customNameVisible) {
    this.customNameVisible = customNameVisible;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public boolean isAllowFlight() {
    return allowFlight;
}

public void setAllowFlight(boolean allowFlight) {
    this.allowFlight = allowFlight;
}

public int getEnergy() {
    return energy;
}

public void setEnergy(int energy) {
    this.energy = energy;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public int getHunger() {
    return hunger;
}

public void setHunger(int hunger) {
    this.hunger = hunger;
}

public int getThirst() {
    return thirst;
}

public void setThirst(int thirst) {
    this.thirst = thirst;
}

public boolean isFalling() {
    return isFalling;
}

public void setFalling(boolean isFalling) {
    this.isFalling = isFalling;
}

public boolean isFlying() {
    return isFlying;
}

public void setFlying(boolean isFlying) {
    this.isFlying = isFlying;
}

public float getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(float experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public int getMaxHealth() {
    return maxHealth;
}

public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) {
    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
}

public String getPlayerListName() {
    return playerListName;
}

public void setPlayerListName(String playerListName) {
    this.playerListName = playerListName;
}

public float getWalkSpeed() {
    return walkSpeed;
}

public void setWalkSpeed(float walkSpeed) {
    this.walkSpeed = walkSpeed;
}

public int getGameMode() {
    return gameMode;
}

public void setGameMode(int gameMode) {
    this.gameMode = gameMode;
}

public String getActualName() {
    return username;
}

public String getUUID() {
    return UUID;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getIPAddress() {
    return IPAddress;
}

public float getX() {
    return Z;
}
public float getY() {
    return Y;
}
public float getZ() {
    return Z;
}

public void jump() {
    if (!isFalling) {
        this.upwardsSpeed = jumpPower;
        isFalling = true;
    } else if (isFalling && allowFlight){
        this.upwardsSpeed = jumpPower * 3f;
        this.walkSpeed = Constants.Player_Run_Speed * 3f;
    }
}

public void checkInputs() throws IOException {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W) && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LCONTROL)) {
        this.currentSpeed = walkSpeed;
    } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        this.currentSpeed = -walkSpeed * 0.96f;
    } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W) && Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LCONTROL)) {
        this.currentSpeed = runSpeed;
    } else {
        this.currentSpeed = 0;
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        if (!thirdPerson) {
            this.currentStraifSpeed = -straifSpeed;
            //MainGameLoop.outToServer.writeBytes("Straifing: RIGHT");
        } else {
            currentTurnSpeed = -turnSpeed;
            //MainGameLoop.outToServer.writeBytes("Tuning: RIGHT");
        }
    } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        if (!thirdPerson) {
            this.currentStraifSpeed = straifSpeed;
            //MainGameLoop.outToServer.writeBytes("Straifing: LEFT");
        } else {
            currentTurnSpeed = turnSpeed;
            //MainGameLoop.outToServer.writeBytes("Tuning: LEFT");
        }
    } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RCONTROL)) {
        MainGameLoop.DEBUG(1,"Debug message here!");
    } else {
        this.currentStraifSpeed = 0;
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
        jump();
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
        gravityPower += 0.5;
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
        gravityPower -= 0.5;
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_NUMPAD0)) {
        gravityPower = 0;
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F)) {
        if (!allowFlight){
            this.allowFlight = true;
        } else {
            this.walkSpeed = Constants.Player_Walk_Speed;
            this.allowFlight = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [monkeyzone](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:monkey_zone) which is a pretty good demo of 3D multiplayer with lwjgl. IT worked for me to take code from there and use in my multiplayer scenario. I recommend jmonkeyengine. If you didn't already try it, give it a chance.